# Random crashes of both Bluetooth and wifi

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, wifi, bluetooth

I am using an M1 Pro 16" Macbook and I recently started getting random crashes of the wifi and Bluetooth, where they disconnect at the same time.
It goes back to normal after 5 to 6 seconds which might indicate driver crashes.

Is there a way to figure out what the issue was?

I am running macOS version 12.2.1 (fairly old by now), with no new updates. I installed a new IDE (pycharm) as my last software install

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Any recent macOS updates installed?

Comment: @nohillside i updated the post with some info,

Comment: 12.2.1 is fairly old, also from a security point of view. Is there a specific reason you can't update to 13.6 at least?